# Lookup cell reference of given value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with hundreds of rows and Column A is a unique record number.

I would like to learn to be able to find cell reference based on the inputted unique record number.

For example if in Call A1, I enter value 11, ho can I retrieve cell row (eg: 17) using google script.

Thank you for help

Taizoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a simple and small Ui that does a "search" in your first column and activates the found cell (and the whole row). An example is shown below, You have an option to use it repeatedly (like it is now) or just once by changing one line of code, see comment at the end of the handler function. :

```
function showInSheet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Search and Select').setWidth(250).setHeight(60);
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var searchHandler = app.createServerHandler('searchRow').addCallbackElement(panel);
  var Hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  var search = app.createTextBox().setName('search').setId('search').setWidth('70').addKeyUpHandler(searchHandler);
  var warning = app.createHTML('incomplete or invalid entry').setId('warning').setStyleAttributes({'padding-left':'10px','background':'yellow','fontSize':'8pt'}).setVisible(false);
  app.add(panel.add(Hpanel.add(search).add(warning)));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().show(app);
}

function searchRow(e){
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var item = e.parameter.search;
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().join().split(',');// the 2D array is "flattened" and splitted to get a 1D array
  Logger.log(data.length);
  var idx = data.indexOf(item);// in a "simple" array we can use this array function more easily to seach in it ;-)
  Logger.log(idx);
  if(idx>data.length || idx==-1){app.getElementById('warning').setVisible(true) ; return app};
  idx++;// increment because rows count from 1 instead of 0 in arrays
  var itemRange = sh.getRange(idx,1,1,sh.getMaxColumns());
  sh.setActiveSelection(itemRange);
//  return app.close();// can be replace by  next line (uncommented)
  app.getElementById('search').setText('');app.getElementById('warning').setVisible(false);return app;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will work off of this example and create a Ui that searches my column.. Thank you very much for your help